# Using context with hooks - TypeError is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks, react-context

I'm learning to use Context with React and Typescript trying to build a form with steps, everytime the user submits a step a new step becomes enabled on the main page. The idea is that every button starts as disabled (except for the first one). But I can't seem to toggle sucessfully to enable/disable the buttons using Context. So far, I've managed to do this:

**Context**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';

interface ModuleContext {
    moduleContact: boolean;
    setModuleContact?: any;
}

const defaultValue: ModuleContext={
  moduleContact: true
};

export const ModuleContext= React.createContext(defaultValue);

export const useModuleContext= () => useContext(ModuleContext);
```

**Main Provider** (putting only a example to not make it too long)

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
  
import { ModuleContext } from './ModuleContext';

const Modules= () => {
  
  const [moduleContact, setModuleContact]= useState<boolean>(true);

   return (
    ...                                
            <ModuleContext.Provider value={{moduleContact, setModuleContact}}>
            <div>
            <IonButton onClick={moduleFirst} <div>First Module</div></IonButton>
            </div>
           
            <div>
            <IonButton disabled={moduleContact} onClick={goContact}</IonButton> 
            </div>
                
          </ModuleContext.Provider>
           </div> 
           </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

**useContext function after onSubmit**

```
import { useModuleContext } from "../ModuleContext";

const FirstModule = () => {

const {moduleContact, setModuleContact}= useModuleContext();
...
const alterContact = () => {
       //console.log('setModule' + setModuleContact);
        setModuleContact(!moduleContact);
    }
        
    const onSubmit = () => {
       alterContact();
       backModules();
    
    }
```

So the error I'm getting is 'TypeError: setModuleContact is not a function'. I'm guessing it's because I'm not defining it as function on the Context, but I really have no idea of how I should do it.

Comment: can you provide a sandbox or stackblitz example of your error?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure how to do it, what would be helpful? Cause it seems to be a very specific error on my function (not recognizing it as function), when I try to console.log all I get is undefined